# Changed the relationship of a Foreign Key | Django model

Tags: django, postgresql

my `buyer field` from the Sell model had relationship with the Buyer model like this:

```
class Buyer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

class Sell(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Buy, related_name='sell', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(**Buyer**, related_name='sell', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

But now, it's set to 'User' model as you can see below:

```
class Sell(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Buy, related_name='sell', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(**User**, related_name='sell', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I go to Django admin, it shows me all the available users from the User model but if I try to save, I got an error like this:

```
insert or update on table "dma_sell" violates foreign key constraint "dma_sell_buyer_id_4d165f92_fk_dma_buyer_id"
DETAIL:  Key (buyer_id)=(13) is not present in table "dma_buyer".
```

I'm wondering I should NOT have changed this but what is the best way to correct that? I really need to relate the buyer field with User model!

Thank you!

Comment: It does not really show the users, it shows the `User` with the primary key of the `Buyer`. That might present a completely different user/`Buyer` object. Changing a `ForeignKey` will need some *data migration*, and likely will be rather "painful".

Comment: @Willem, what if I backup all my database and start it all again? The point is: my Buyer model can be erased because it won't be necessary anymore. All the users will be selected from the User model.

Comment: the problem is not the database. Likely the database did not change, that is why you get a FK violation, because it sees that you enter user id `13`, and that no `buyer` with that pk exists. The problem is that before you can migrate it, you will need to map each buyer to its user in the `Sell` table.

Comment: But why Django is looking for a user id 13 in `buyer`? It should look inside the User, because is now pointing to that model... I mean, is there any simple solution for this case? The database is not so big, maybe I could do this manually...

Comment: because you first constructed a table with a foreign key on the `Buyer` table. So that means Django will add a `Foreign Key` constraint to ensure that ids refer to valid `Buyer` records.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, is there a way to drop only this `buyer` field and then recreate with the correct User model relatioship?

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a long time, I discovered 2 great websites!

Links:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html
https://aistlabs.com/switch-foreignkey-one-model-another-and-keep-old-data-migration-pain/

Just recording here for those who can ask in the future!